# Pods Framework List Items Widget

Tags: wordpress, pods-framework

I'm building a Wordpress site using Pods and Elementor. My posts have a Pod text field called 'year'. I'm trying to use the Where parameter in the Pods-List Items widget to filter the posts by 'year.'  But I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  year='2020' doesn't work and the same with many other attempts. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Also interested in finding the syntax for this. Relative date filters must surely be possible too - `field < NOW()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pods can be filtered by means of a shortcode. The list-items widget is just a tool that helps you easily make such a shortcode.

To add the year filter, you'd do something like this:

**By shortcode directly**

```
 [pods name="my_pod_name" 
where="year.meta_value = '2021'" template="template_name_if_using_one"]
```

**In the Pods widget**

In the "where" field, you'd just write:

```
year.meta_value = 'value_to_filter'
```

The important bit, and which people frequently forget, is **adding the .meta_value** to the the field name they're filtering on.